# Which is the best (most H/s) open source NVidia driver for Linux (any distro)

Tags: mining, linux, gpu

I have tested my **GTX 860M** on **Arch Linux** with two diffrent drivers, but the diffrence is **insignifiant** (<0.3 MH/s). Is there a specific combo of *NVidia driver* + *Linux Distro* that gets most out of a video card?

Using **ethminer**, with **CUDA**, getting **~4.x MH/s**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there aren't big differences in drivers version, buy ymmv

On a side note, you can check [this website](http://62.212.74.86/~mining/list/amd/index.php?algo=eth) for a list of configurations / drivers info and hashrate.

Please note that the reported hashrate is what it is at the time it is reported so it's rather useless in my opinion since the difficulty changes over time, etc. I mined at 23MH/s back in september, same cards yield at best 17 now, same configs.

You can also dig into [this thread](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2134/gpu-mining-is-out-come-and-let-us-know-of-your-bench-scores) but the same caveats apply.

Comment: Quite useful that website, I will switch to Ubuntu and try multiple combinations until I get the most out of the video card. Thank you.

Comment: honestly I don't think you'll be able to draw statistically significant conclusions from running various driver versions : there are so many variables impacting your hashrate and so much volatility in hashrate for a given configuration that you'll end up explaining noise most likely. I wouldn't bother ;)

Comment: "hashrate is what it is at the time it is reported so it's rather useless in my opinion since the difficulty changes over time," - the change in speed has nothing to do with difficulty

Answer (score 2):

Just a side node, I use ArchLinux on all my devices, but when it comes to mining I just use a stock Ubuntu installation because they have the best proprietary driver support.

So without answering your question regarding the driver itself, I would recommend stepping out and (if that's possible for you) consider running Ubuntu and maybe you have the chance to compare the results.

There is also [EthOs](http://ethosdistro.com/) which is based on Ubuntu but comes with preinstalled binaries and drivers for mining. Might give it a try?

Comment: I looked into EthOS, but I don't like the little to none presence of support. Thank you for your answer, I will look into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous poster mentioned the hashrate is going to change based on difficulty. But if it helps you I have a GTX 980Ti that only hashes at 5.5MH/s right now... so yours sounds about right. (Mine is overclocked as well). The Nvidia cards just don't really excel at what Ethereum/Bitcoin/Litecoin need.

Comment: Hashrate is not related to difficulty.